# NinjaValidationException

Tags: validation, error, exception, standard-objects, collaborationgroup

I encountered the following exception when trying to insert a `CollaborationGroup` in a test:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, content.common.sfc.exception.NinjaValidationException: workspaceName - This field is required: []

Thing is, this object does not appear to have any field called `workspaceName`, at least according to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_collaborationgroup.htm). Has anyone else encountered this error in this or any other context? Are there known workarounds?

Comment: Dwarves, and now ninjas?

Comment: I know right? Mysterious, but at least it's humorous.

Comment: Found a couple of other users with the same issue, one stated to ensure you do not have duplicate group names, https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008ztHIAQ. Another stated that you need to make sure content is enabled in your org, https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008zXZIAY. The last one states that it is a bug, https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DoXTAA0.

Comment: @JennyB I made the names unique, but did not make sure content is enabled. I will try that before writing it off entirely as a bug. Thanks!

Comment: where's SFSE user `sfdc_ninja` when you need him/her?

Comment: @AdrianLarson just curious how you made out with this one?

Comment: @JennyB Ended up being related to a completely different field (`CollaborationType`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to having a unique `Name`, the `CollaborationGroup` object requires the `CollaborationType` picklist to be populated. It has the following options:

> **Public**—Anyone can see and post updates. Anyone can join a public group.
>
> **Private**—Only members can see the group feed and post updates. Non-members can only see the group name and a few other details in list views, search, and on the group page. The group's owner or managers must add members who request to join the group.
>
> **Unlisted**—Only members and users with the “Manage Unlisted Groups” permission can see the group and post updates. Other users can’t access the group or see it in lists, search, and feeds.